# Counting of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Please tell me how I can calculate how many rows have been updated and added to the table from the CSV file. My code with which I update or add data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3
import csv
import time

database_name = "/root/Test/test.db"
csv_file_name = "/root/test.csv"
print("[!] Updating the database...")
con = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
cur = con.cursor()
with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    test = [(i['column_1'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'], i['column_4'], 
             i['column_5'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'],
             i['column_4'], i['column_5'],) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, "
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                "ON CONFLICT(column_1) DO UPDATE SET "
                "column_2 = ?, column_3 = ?, column_4 = ?, column_5 = ?,", test)
con.commit()
con.close()
time.sleep(1)
print("[+] The database is updated!")
```

Comment: untill you commit all of them or one by one, you won't know how much actually saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by counting the length of the table before the update and after like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3
import csv
import time

database_name = "/root/Test/test.db"
csv_file_name = "/root/test.csv"
print("[!] Updating the database...")
con = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
table_count_before = con.execute("select COUNT(*) as count from mytable").fetchall()
cur = con.cursor()
with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    test = [(i['column_1'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'], i['column_4'],
             i['column_5'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'],
             i['column_4'], i['column_5'],) for i in dr]


cur.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, "
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                "ON CONFLICT(column_1) DO UPDATE SET "
                "column_2 = ?, column_3 = ?, column_4 = ?, column_5 = ?,", test)
con.commit()
table_count_after = con.execute("select COUNT(*) as count from mytable").fetchall()
print(f"Update {table_count_after[0].count - table_count_before[0].count} rows")
con.close()
time.sleep(1)
print("[+] The database is updated!")
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3
import csv
import time

database_name = "/root/Test/test.db"
csv_file_name = "/root/test.csv"
print("[!] Updating the database...")
con = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
table_count_before = con.execute("select * from mytable").fetchall()
cur = con.cursor()
with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    test = [(i['column_1'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'], i['column_4'],
             i['column_5'], i['column_2'], i['column_3'],
             i['column_4'], i['column_5'],) for i in dr]


cur.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, "
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                "ON CONFLICT(column_1) DO UPDATE SET "
                "column_2 = ?, column_3 = ?, column_4 = ?, column_5 = ?,", test)
con.commit()
table_count_after = con.execute("select * from mytable").fetchall()
print(f"Update {len(table_count_after) - len(table_count_before)} rows")
con.close()
time.sleep(1)
print("[+] The database is updated!")
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! I like this method, it works! Can you please tell me how cost-effective this method will be if the table contains more than 50 thousand rows, how about security and memory, will there be no problems?

Comment: Your method shows how many lines have been added, it would be nice to show how many lines have been changed / updated

Comment: I've changed the answer to use the `count` function of the SQLite to be more efficient for a large number of records. About the change/update, it's more complicated to tell.

Comment: Please change your answer in the line:
`table_count_before = con.execute("select COUNT(*) as coun from mytable").fetchall()`
on this:
`table_count_before = con.execute("select COUNT(*) as coun from mytable").fetchall()`
typo in request  `count`

Comment: With the new method, I get this error:
*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'*

Comment: I've updated the query. I'm not sure about the `builtin_function_or_method` error.

Answer (score 1):

To see the number of rows updated and added you can use,

```
cur.rowcount
```

Comment: I'm not a Python developer, I'm just putting together a handy tool to use something. Could you specifically show on my example how exactly to apply your cur.rowcount method...do not consider this as arrogance, I just learn and want to understand, and a specific example will help me with this. if you have any documentation on this method, I will be glad. Thank you!